# Can not  access files using live usb 

Tags: 11.10, live-usb, external-hdd

My hard drive has errors so ubuntu wouldn't load! I tried the live usb to take a backup of my data! I had two accounts...I can access the data of one account but for the data of other account it says:

`only the owner has the permission or can't access the files`

The data was of 40 GB but it only shows 1.2 MB and some unreadable contents! It doesn't even show the contents! Please help...the data is important!

Comment: Open the home directory using nautilus. Open terminal and write `sudo nautilus` this will help you give a root permission to access all directory's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the home directory using nautilus.

- Open a terminal and write:

  `sudo nautilus`

This will help you giving a root permission to access all directory's.